# Getting error while upgrading to Magento 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I get following error:

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column ‘position’ in order clause is ambiguous`

I was having Magento 1.4 version, firstly I successfully upgraded it to 1.6.2, but when I tried upgrading it to 1.7, I came up with above error.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

1. Locate table `eav_attribute` in phpmyadmin, which was related to `catalog_eav_attribute`.
   Located column `position` in table `eav_attribute` and dropped it.
2. Clear all cache and reindexed all data
3. Now visit front page. Now you might get a new error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ‘main_table.include_in_menu’ in ‘where clause’

1. Locate and open file `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php`

Comment out following line:267

```
->where(‘main_table.is_active = ?’, ’1′)
// ->where(‘main_table.include_in_menu = ?’, ’1′)
->order(‘main_table.position’);
```

You can find a step by step guide at:
expertmagentodevelopers[dot]com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-magento-1-6-1-to-1-7-0-using-connect-manager/

The above solution is based on my own experience.